# Accessing Nested JSON String Array

Tags: java, android, json

I have a JSON object that looks like this

```
{"layout":[["12","21","31"],["empty","22","32"],["13","23","33"]]}
```

I am trying to get the array data within with:

```
JSONObject layoutJson;
JSONArray  layoutData = layoutJson.getJSONArray();
```

However I end up with a single entry in the array of

```
[["12","21","31"],["empty","22","32"],["13","23","33"]]
```

How do I get this out of the JSON object in the form of 3 arrays?

Comment: Iterate the array elements, they'll each be `JSONArray` values.

Comment: basically, you wanna get 3 separate arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
JSONObject layoutJson;
JSONArray  layoutData = layoutJson.getJSONArray();
for (int i = 0; i < layoutData.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject firstArray = (JSONObject)layoutData.getJSONObject(i);
    // Do whatever you want with first array
    // you can loop through the first array again
}
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation not just only the answer.
Thank you.

Comment: Throws a JSON exception however changing first Array to a JSONArray solved all issues. Thanks, does exactly what i was trying to do.

Comment: First capture the json object. then create a json array from that object. Get first json object from that array using loop. thats all.